# OpenAM: Error processing AuthnRequest. null

Tags: saml-2.0, openam

When trying to init an SSO via OpenAM, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Error processing AuthnRequest. null
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Error processing AuthnRequest. null).
```

The logs are linking to the method `AMKeyProvider.getPrivateKey`, (NullPointerException), so I know a private key can't be read.
However, I'm new to OpenAM/SAML and don't know where/how to fix this issue.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
 libSAML2:10/17/2014 12:06:41:247 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8443-exec-8,5,main]
ERROR: Error processing Request 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.forgerock.openam.utils.AMKeyProvider.getPrivateKey(AMKeyProvider.java:269)
    at com.sun.identity.saml.xmlsig.JKSKeyProvider.getPrivateKey(JKSKeyProvider.java:112)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPSSOFederate.signQueryString(SPSSOFederate.java:1125)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPSSOFederate.initiateAuthnRequest(SPSSOFederate.java:346)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPSSOFederate.initiateAuthnRequest(SPSSOFederate.java:146)
    at org.apache.jsp.saml2.jsp.spSSOInit_jsp._jspService(spSSOInit_jsp.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is pointing to:
    org.forgerock.openam.utils.AMKeyProvider.getPrivateKey(AMKeyProvider.java:269)

The method `getPrivateKey`looks like this:

```
public java.security.PrivateKey getPrivateKey (String certAlias) {
   java.security.PrivateKey key = null;
   try {
       key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(certAlias,
               privateKeyPass.toCharArray());
   } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
       logger.error(e.getMessage());
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       logger.error(e.getMessage());
   } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
       logger.error(e.getMessage());
   }
   return key;
```

}

Thus, there is either no keystore at all at the expected path, no valid key with the corresponding alias in the keystore, or the keystore and/or key password is wrong.

The keystore path (as well as the path to the files containing the **encrypted** passwords) can be seen in the openAM admin web UI under *Configuration* - *Servers and Sites* - myServerName - *Security*, typically:

```
%BASE_DIR%/%SERVER_URI%/keystore.jks
```

, where `%BASE_DIR%` is configured under *Configuration* - *Servers and Sites* - myServerName - *General*.

Answer (score 1):

You may check

http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/admin-guide/index.html#set-up-federation

there is a specific SAML keystore you have to  configure.

Comment: thanks for the helpful link. However, I found the solution to my problem as described in my answer.